# Can't get items from Orders, Magento

Tags: java, api, magento

I'm writing a Java connector for `Magento API` using **magja** library.

When I retrieve `Orders` from my test store, I can get all order info (`id`, `total_amount`, etc.) except for `OrderItems`. The list is always empty although the order has items.

Here's the code:

```
List<Order> orders = RemoteServiceFactory.getOrderRemoteService().list();
for (Order order : orders) {
    List<OrderItem> items = order.getItems();
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it doing this:

```
List<Order> orders = RemoteServiceFactory.getOrderRemoteService().list();
for (Order order : orders) {
    Order orderInfo = RemoteServiceFactory.getOrderRemoteService().getById(order.getId());
    List<OrderItem> items = orderInfo.getItems();
}
```

What happened is that `Order` inside the `orders` list retrieved by `getOrderRemoteService().list();` method doesn't really have the items inside, although method `getItems()` is part of `Order` class.

Actually, the item list is populated only when execute the request to obtain a single Order by its ID.

Magento API reference for orders list and order info:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html